# Android photo download from ftp server

Tags: java, android, ftp

I want to know how to:

```
1. connect to ftp server
2. list all the files in a folder
3. select a photo from the ftp server
4. download it on my device,show this photo on screen.
```

This is for an android application.

thnx for your help.

Comment: Please try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: To download and show the photo on your device is pretty straight forward, but you need to provide more details as to be able to help more.